# Combining these MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, join, pdo

I am learning MySQL and messing about with joins. I am wondering if I can cut these queries down and combine them. This is what I would NORMALLY do:

```
$stmt = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT date, table2_id, comments 
                          FROM table1 
                          WHERE user = "victor"');
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  $table2_id = $row['table2_id'];
}

$stmt = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT table3_id 
                          FROM table2 
                          WHERE table2_id = '.$table2_id.'');
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  $table3_id = $row['table3_id'];
}

$stmt = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT previous_comments_count 
                          FROM table3 
                          WHERE table3_id = '.$table3_id.'');
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  $table3_id = $row['table3_id'];
}
```

(I changed the variables, so it looks stupid on purpose--I did not design the table for this company)

Basically, I need to get most of my information from the first table, but there is one "id" that needs to cross two tables that I would like to put into the first query.

So what I tried was:

```
$stmt = $db_pdo->prepare('SELECT date, table2_id, comments 
                          FROM table1 
                          LEFT JOIN table2 
                                 ON table1.table2_id = table2.table2_id 
                          LEFT JOIN table3 
                                 ON table2.table3_id = table3.table3_id 
                          WHERE user = "victor"');
```

And obviously my first (and many tweaked versions of this line) have failed, leading to a blank fetch.

I can do the first left join, but even that doesn't seem to show the information from the second table. The second and third tables do not have the same columns as the first table. (I don't think this is a problem but I could be wrong.)

I've done some reading on various websites, and though I love figuring out my problems on my own, I think it's best to ask if what I'm trying to accomplish is even possible and to try and get it done ASAP. I've read some other questions like this, but I am just simply befuddled looking at the complexity of this let alone those ones. (It's one of those days...)

It could be that I'm also using pdo and prepared statements for the first time as well, I do NOT think that's the problem, but I apologize if it is. I'm not a MySQL genius and have not spent much time with databases.

Also (side question, if permitted): Do I have to use foreach? Or can I just trust that calling $stmt after the execute is good enough? (AKA passes true/false on the ONE result that should show up)

Answer (score 0):

Try the joins like this:

```
table3
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table3.table3_id = table2.table3_id
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table2.table2_id = table1.table2_id
```